# About Laziness [ RAKU ]

Tags: arrays, lazy-evaluation, raku, lazy-sequences, rakudo

In Raku documentation it is stated that gather-take constructs are being lazy evaluated. In the following examples I have a hard time concluding about the laziness of the constructs:

```
say 'Iterate to Infinity is : ', (1 ... Inf).WHAT;

say 'gather is : ', gather {
    take 0;
    my ($last, $this) = 0, 1;

    loop {
        take $this;
        ($last, $this) = $this, $last + $this;
    }
}.WHAT;

say '------------------------------------';

my @f1 = lazy gather {
    take 0;
    my ($last, $this) = 0, 1;

    loop {
        take $this;
        ($last, $this) = $this, $last + $this;
    }
}

say '@f1         : ', @f1.WHAT;
say '@f1 is lazy : ', @f1.is-lazy;

say '------------------------------------';

my @f2 = 1 ... Inf;

say '@f2         : ', @f2.WHAT;
say '@f2 is lazy : ', @f2.is-lazy;
```

In the first case (assignement of a Seq to @f1) if we take away the "lazy" definition then the generated Sequence (with use of gather-take) is running forever (NOT lazy).

In the second case (assignement of a Seq to @f2) @f2 becomes lazy.

Why do we have a differentiation in behaviour? although we try to do the same thing: Assign a Seq to an array in a lazy way

Can someone clarify the matter ???

Comment: "In Raku documentation it is stated that gather-take constructs are being lazy evaluated." They *can* be. But not necessarily. Please provide a link to which particular doc you're reading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In Raku documentation it is stated that gather-take constructs are being lazy evaluated.

They *can* be. But not necessarily. They're perfectly happy to work either way.

In a key twist, if a `gather` is *asked* if it's lazy, it returns `False`. This is what results in the behaviour you see.

## Take #1: One way `gather` behaves *lazily*

`gather` evaluates the next element in its sequence when it's needed. This is [the classic definition of lazy evaluation, as described by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation):

> lazy evaluation ... delays the evaluation of an expression until its value is needed

## Take #2: A second way `gather` behaves *lazily*

Some constructs that consume sequences of values always consume them lazily. If the sequence they're consuming is a `gather`, they demand its values lazily. In which case the `gather` obliges, evaluating its sequence until it reaches a `take`, and then [yielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)#:%7E:text=yield%20control%20back%20to%20the%20caller) until the next value is demanded.

## Take #3: One way `gather` behaves *eagerly*

Some constructs that consume sequences of values always consume them eagerly. If a sequence they're consuming is a `gather`, they demand its values eagerly. In which case the `gather` obliges, and any laziness in it is moot.

## Take #4: A second way `gather` behaves *eagerly*

Some constructs that consume sequences of values demand them *either* lazily *or* eagerly, based on the sequence's answer to an `.is-lazy` call on it; if it returns `True`, then its values are demanded lazily, otherwise they're demanded eagerly.

And here comes a critical twist: when `.is-lazy` is called on a `gather` construct, it returns `False`.

## Take #5: What's happening in your examples

```
say .is-lazy
for (gather { take 42 }),                 # False
    (gather { loop { take 42 } });        # False
```

In your `@f1 = gather ...` case, `@f1` is being assigned a sequence that says it's *not* lazy. This is so even though it contains an infinite loop. `@` sigil'd variables take that as a cue to *eagerly* assign the sequence -- and the code hangs.

---

The prefix `lazy` creates a new `Seq` that lazily draws from the expression on its right. It also returns `True` if `.is-lazy` is called on it:

```
say .is-lazy
for (lazy gather { take 42 }),            # True
    (lazy gather { loop { take 42 } });   # True
```

If an `@` sigil'd variable is assigned a value that returns `True` for a call to `.is-lazy`, the assignment, and the variable, are lazy. So the code `@f1 = lazy gather ...` works fine.

---

Finally, the sequence `(1...Inf)` *knows* it's lazy, and tells the world it is, without needing a prefix `lazy`:

```
say .is-lazy with (1 ... Inf)             # True
```

So assigning that also works fine, with or without `lazy`.

---

In summary, an `@` sigil'd variable gains elements lazily if a `Seq` assigned to it says it's lazy, and eagerly otherwise.

---

You didn't ask about this, but another scenario is assigning or binding a `Seq` to a `$` sigil'd variable, or a sigil free identifier.

As with a `@` sigil'd variable, calling `.is-lazy` on the `$` sigil'd variable or sigil free identifier will return `True` or `False` in accord with the assigned/bound `Seq`.

But then, *regardless* of whether that `.is-lazy` returns `True` or `False`, the `Seq` will still be iterated *lazily*.

Comment: FWIW, I find `say .is-lazy with 1..Inf` clearer to read, as it won't make you think it might iterate over the range,