# What persistent data structures does Raku/Rakudo include?

Tags: functional-programming, immutability, raku, rakudo

Raku provides [many](https://docs.raku.org/type/ValueObjAt) types that are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and thus cannot be modified after they are created.  Until I started looking into this area recently, my understanding was that these Types were *not* [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Usage_in_programming_languages) – that is, unlike the core types in Clojure or Haskell, my belief was that Raku's immutable types did not take advantage of structural sharing to allow for inexpensive copies.  I thought that statement `my List $new = (|$old-list, 42);` literally copied the values in `$old-list`, without the data-sharing features of persistent data structures.

That description of my understanding is in the past tense, however, due to the following code:

```
my Array $a = do {
    $_ = [rand xx 10_000_000];
    say "Initialized an Array in $((now - ENTER now).round: .001) seconds"; $_}
my List $l = do {
    $_ = |(rand xx 10_000_000);
    say "Initialized the List in $((now - ENTER now).round: .001) seconds"; $_}
do { $a.push: rand;  
     say "Pushed the element to the Array in $((now - ENTER now).round: .000001) seconds" }
do { my $nl = (|$l, rand); 
     say "Appended an element to the List in $((now - ENTER now).round: .000001) seconds" }
do { my @na = |$l; 
     say "Copied List \$l into a new Array in $((now - ENTER now).round: .001) seconds" }
```

which produced this output in one run:

```
Initialized an Array in 5.938 seconds
Initialized the List in 5.639 seconds
Pushed the element to the Array in 0.000109 seconds
Appended an element to the List in 0.000109 seconds
Copied List $l into a new Array in 11.495 seconds
```

That is, creating a new List with the old values + one more is just as fast as pushing to a mutable Array, and dramatically faster than copying the List into a new Array – exactly the performance characteristics that you'd expect to see from a persistent List (copying to an Array is still slow because it can't take advantage of structural sharing without breaking the immutability of the List).  The fast copying of `$l` into `$nl` is *not* due to either List being lazy; neither are.

All of the above leads me to believe that Lists in Rakudo actually *are* persistent data structures, with all the performance benefits that implies. That leaves me with several questions:

- Am I right about Lists being persistent data structures?
- Are all other immutable Types *also* persistent data structures? Or are any?
- Is any of this part of Raku, or just an implementation choice Rakudo has made?
- Are any of these performance characteristics documented/guaranteed anywhere?

I have to say, I am both extremely impressed and more than a bit baffled to discover evidence that at least some of Raku(do)'s types are persistent.  It's the sort of feature that other languages [list as a key selling point](https://clojure.org/about/rationale#_functional_programming_is_a_good_thing) or that leads to the creation of [libraries with 30k+ stars](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js) on GitHub.  Have we really had it in Raku without even mentioning it?

Comment: By definition, it won't be a "persistent" data structure unless it is absolutely protected from Garbage Collection, correct?

Comment: @codesections "The fast copying of `$l` into `$nl` is not due to either `List` being lazy; neither are." Are you relying on `.is-lazy`? Per [its doc](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is-lazy), with my added ***emphasis***, `is-lazy` "Returns `True` if and only if the underlying iterator or cached list [or sequence] ***considers itself*** lazy.", but see also [my answer to SO "About Laziness"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59790723/1077672), and behaviour I've made visible by using [a modified version of your code](https://replit.com/@RalphMellor/SO-what-persistent-data-structures#main.raku).

Comment: @jubilatious1: How does that property follow from the definition of a persistent data structure? The only real requirement for a persistent data structure is that if I have a reference to it, and someone else modifies the data structure, I should still have access to my version of it. We generally also require that operations are efficient (i.e. comparable to an equivalent non-persistent data structure) and that all versions are equally efficient, but those are desirable properties, not technically part of the definition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I remember implementing these semantics, and I certainly don't recall thinking about them giving rise to a persistent data structure at the time - although it does seems fair to attach that label to the result!

I don't think you'll find anywhere that explicitly spells out this exact behavior, however the most natural implementation of things that *are* required by the language quite naturally leads to it. Taking the ingredients:

- The `infix:<,>` operator is the `List` constructor in Raku
- When a `List` is created, it is non-committal with regards to laziness and flattening (these arise from how we use the `List`, which we don't - in general - know at the point of its construction)
- When we write `(|$x, 1)`, the `prefix:<|>` operator constructs a `Slip`, which is a kind of `List` that should melt into its surrounding `List`. Thus what `infix:<,>` sees is a `Slip` and an `Int`.
- Making the `Slip` melt into the result `List` immediately would mean making a commitment about eagerness, which `List` construction alone should not do. Thus the `Slip` and everything after it is placed into the lazily evaluated ("non-reified") portion of the `List`.

This last of these is what gives rise to the observed persistent data structure style behavior.

I expect it would be possible to have a implementation that inspects the `Slip` and chooses to eagerly copy things that are known not to be lazy, and still be in compliance with the specification test suite. That would change the time complexity of your example. If you want to be defensive against that, then:

```
do { my $nl = (|$l.lazy, rand); 
     say "Appended an element to the List in $((now - ENTER now).round: .000001) seconds" }
```

Should be sufficient to force the issue even if the implementation changed.

Of other cases that immediately come to mind that are related to persistent data structures or at least tail sharing:

- The MoarVM implementation of strings, which is behind `str` and thus `Str`, implements string concatenation by creating a new string that refers to the two that are being concatenated instead of copying the data in the two strings (and does similar tricks for `substr` and repetition). This is strictly an optimization, not a language requirement, and in some delicate cases (the last grapheme of one string and the first grapheme of the next will form a single grapheme in the resulting string), it gives up and takes the copying path.
- Outside of the core, modules like `Concurrent::Stack`, `Concurrent::Queue`, and `Concurrent::Trie` use tail sharing as a technique to implement relatively efficient lock-free data structures.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the last bullet, though.  `(|$l).is-lazy` returns `False` – so are you saying that the internal storage of the `Slip` is lazy (/non-reified) even though the Slip itself isn't?  Also, do you happen to know whether the same structural sharing behavior is present in Maps/other immutable types?

Comment: @codesections Regarding `is-lazy`, please see comment I've added to your question.

Comment: @codesections At the time we construct a `List` with `infix:<,>` we don't know if it's going to be lazy or not. In an expression like `lazy |$a, |$b`, the `List` of `|$a, |$b` is constructed *and then* it is marked lazy by calling `.lazy` on it. If, as part of `infix:<,>`, we were to go expanding the slipped `$a` because it's `is-lazy` happens to return `False`, by the time we get to mark it lazy it's too late. (The general Raku design principle here is that things preserve information until we put them in a context that forces a particular interpretation.)

Comment: @codesections I don't believe there's anything similar going on with `Map` at present; the design forces that result in this behavior on `List` don't exist for `Map` (they are never lazy nor involved in flattening list lists are). I already mentioned the `Str` implementation detail. I'm not sure how `Rat`s look inside at present, but I think they normalize at construction time, so in general don't get to share the `Int`s they are constructed from in general.